# Register Mapping Problem in STM32 Micro-controller

Tags: c++, c, stm32, microcontroller, stm32cubeide

I am using Micro-controller STM32-L476RG. I am facing a problem in RCC Register Mapping.

Please take a look at the picture. You will notice I declared a structured `typedef struct` of `RCC_RegDef_t` where all the register values are in the correct order. The Problem is when the code executing `RCC->AHB2ENR  |= GPIOAEN;`  this line of code in the `main` function, it should store the value in AHB2ENR register. But it is storing the value in APB2RSTR register. I am not finding why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: use CMSIS headers. Your hard work is rather useless

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you don't need to use the `typedef struct` when declaring variables, parameters or return values from functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your type definition lacks some entries, especially for the offsets 0x24, 0x34 and 0x44. See the snippet:

[image]

Correct your definition by inserting "unused" entries:

```c
    _vo uint32_t CICR;
    _vo uint32_t unused1;
    _vo uint32_t AHB1RSTR;
```

Otherwise the compiler does not know that you want `AHB1RSTR` to be at offset 0x28.

Comment: But in reference Manual, there is nothing about these two offsets. Also IN SFRs view, it is also missing, what can I do, in that case?

Comment: @AbuSayed It doesn't explicitly say anything but it's supposedly some reserved addresses. You need to declare dummy variables at those locations. `_vo uint32_t dummy1;` etc. See 6.4.33 of the manual. Or better yet, write every single register in the MCU as an unique uint32_t declared at an absolute address. ST's way of writing register maps is error-prone and fishy in general.

Comment: @AbuSayed The expected way to say "Thank you" is to mark the best answer. You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: @ the busybee, I don't have 15 reputations to cast a vote.  But I already tried that. Thank you again.

Comment: Accepting an answer (to "mark") is different from casting a vote. AFAIK you should be able to accept without a certain reputation, perhaps after some time.